# While performing multiplication returns Nan in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, pagination

I am trying pagination in nodejs.while multiplication it returns Nan .I tried parseInt ,no use.Below is my code

```
router.route('/imagecard/get/paginate/:pageno').get((req, res) => {

    let perpage=5;
    let pageNo=req.params.pageno;
    let query={};

    query.skip= parseInt( perpage )* (parseInt(pageNo) -1);
    console.log(parseInt( perpage ) * (parseInt(pageNo)-1));
    console.log(query.skip);
    query.limit=  perpage;

    ImageCard.find({}, {}, query, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ "error": true, "message": "error fetching data" });
        } else {
            res.json(data);
        }
    }).sort({ "name": 1 });

});
```

this particular line returns Nan

```
query.skip= parseInt( perpage )* (parseInt(pageNo) -1);
```

Even I tried this one

```
query.skip = perpage * (pageNo - 1);
```

Comment: First of all, try to find out the value of your `pageNo` variable. It looks very possible that you get `undefined` when trying to retrieve it from request parameters `req.params.pageno`. Try to debug or simply print the value to the console.

Comment: @Vaidas all variables are getting values correctly but when I do multiplication it returns Nan for query.skip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this happens is that `parseInt` return `NaN` when you can't convert that value to a number (`null`, `undefined`, `string`, `[]`, `{}`).

[image]

And probably it happens in this part `parseInt(pageNo)` because `req.params.pageno` is probably undefined.

What you can do is do some checking to make it 0 if you want so.

Change

```
let pageNo=req.params.pageno;
```

To

```
let pageNo = Number.isNaN(req.params.pageno) ? 0 : req.params.pageno;
```

> Adding `|| 0` will make `pageNo` to `0` when `req.params.pageno` is `null` or undefined`, you can also change it to any number you want.

## Edit:

Maybe you have a typo?

Shouldn't `req.params.pageno`

```
let pageNo = req.params.pageno;
```

Be `req.params.pageNo`

```
                 // capital N
let pageNo = req.params.pageNo;
```

## Edit 2:

> it just returns 0 .if the passed parameter is 2 ,returns 0.not skipping the already shown rows

I just tested it, and with parameter 2, it's returning 5.

[image]

I'm not sure what you want to do, not sure how many you want to skip, maybe change your logic? Or instead of `0`, but it `1`? Now you need to see what are your requirements to solve this situation.

## Full Code

```
router.route('/imagecard/get/paginate/:pageno').get((req, res) => {

    let perpage=5;
    let pageNo = Number.isNaN(req.params.pageno) ? 0 : req.params.pageno;
    let query={};

    query.skip = parseInt( perpage )* (parseInt(pageNo) -1);
    console.log(parseInt( perpage ) * (parseInt(pageNo)-1));
    console.log(query.skip);
    query.limit = perpage;

    ImageCard.find({}, {}, query, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ "error": true, "message": "error fetching data" });
        } else {
            res.json(data);
        }
    }).sort({ "name": 1 });

});
```

Working Snippet

```js
    let reqParamsPageno = 2
    console.log('req.params.pageno', reqParamsPageno)
    let perpage = 5;
    let pageNo = reqParamsPageno;
    let query = {};
    query.skip = parseInt(perpage) * (parseInt(pageNo) -1);
    query.limit =  perpage;
    console.log('query', query);
```

Comment: what changes I have to make now

Comment: Tried ,it returns Nan.I am receiving all the values.

Comment: @Karthi sorry, I forgot one case, when the variable is a string that can't be converted to a number, it will be `NaN`, so you need to check if `isNaN` before `parseInt`. I just updated my answer.

Comment: it just returns 0 .if the passed parameter is 2 ,returns 0.not skipping the already shown rows

Comment: @Karthi, check my edit, make sure you are doing it right.

Comment: Even I tested that.It doesn't works in actual code .For First time it returns 5 rows,when pageNo=1,which is correct.For pageNo=2 ,It must show other 5 rows .but it is returning previous 5 rows ,because of  query.skip = Nan.i want query.skip to be 5 for pageNo=2.

Comment: @Karthi, I just add an edit on my answer that shows that when `pageNo=2`, `query.skip = 5`. Please add the code that is no working on your question, maybe you are doing something wrong. I will also add the full to to my answer

Comment: Solved. I made mistake in api call .thanks @Vencovsky